# Is it possible to create a pool to parallelize a for cycle that already as a pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

my question is imagine you have a for cycle where inside you create a pool. For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

cpus = mp.cpu_count()-1
for i in A:
    pool = mp.Pool(cpus)
    sma = pool.startmap_async(function, parameters)
    result = sma.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Where `function` is any function and `parameters` the parameters of the function. In order to parallelize could I put what is inside the loop in a function and create a pool where I would call that new function? So like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def function1():
    ## put what is inside the loop
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool2 = Pool()                         
    pool2.map(function1, new_parameters)
```

Comment: well, have you tried it?

Comment: No, I was trying to learn if it was possible because I don't know much about pools. That is why it's an hypothetical example. No need to be rude.

Comment: you should be able to do that

Comment: @DPM we're not being rude, we are trying to be as useful for you as we can, that's why we are in this question. We just saw a more general solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You can try it as short as

```
def f(x):
    return list(Pool(10).map(sleep, [60] * 1000))

print(list(Pool(15).map(f, range(1000))))
```

You'll see 151 processes in `top`.

A really valuable knowledge (no irony, and thanks for brining this up) is that such questions are answered by experimenting.